# How to adjust block element's bounding box to fit next to floated element?

Tags: css, width, css-float, block

For example, I want the h1 element to adjust in size to fit in next to the floated red div. The text is already adjusting to the float, but the background goes behind the floated element.

I know I can add a right margin to h1, but the red block can be of variable width and I can't have a variable margin.

CSS:

```
#redblock {            
    background: red;
    float: right;
    margin: 10px;
    width: 100px;
    height:100px;
}
#wrapper {
    border: 1px solid black;
    margin: 10px;
    padding: 10px;
    width: 300px;
}
p {
    background-color: #ffd;
}
h1 {
    background-color: #667788;
    font-size: 1.1em;
    margin: 10px 0;
}
```

HTML:

```
<div id="wrapper">
    <div id="redblock"></div>

    <h1>Test tEst teSt tesT</h1>

    <p>Test tEst teSt tesT Test tEst teSt tesT Test tEst teSt tesT Test tEst teSt tesT Test tEst teSt
    tesT Test tEst teSt tesT Test tEst teSt tesT</p>
</div>
```

See http://jsbin.com/ucili4

Comment: I think I found a solution. Adding `overflow: hidden` to `h1` has the desired effect. Tested in FF.

See http://jsbin.com/ucili4/2

Answer (score 0):

if you add a `width:80%` for `h1` will make a width that will find the middle of the current red box. So if you have bigger, or a little smaller red box I suppose it will work. (probably the gray background, is for test purposes, right?)

example: http://jsbin.com/okive4

Comment: Thanks, but I would still have to guess a percentage, which doesn't really solve the problem. And yes, the background is just for testing, I might also want to use a border...